# Parallel processing of Directory

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I am working on File directory monitoring in which i have to look for a specific directory "D:\Watch" and if there is any new file detects i have to process it and show the contents. I was using FileSystemWatcher but my requirement is to check directory for every 1 minute.That's why i skip the FileSystemWatcher and make a Windows service which is schedule after every 1 minute and read the directory to process the new files.

But my requirement is to read the files in Parallel and show the contents after the file is processed and don't need to wait for other files to be processed. I also need to handle the exception if any of the file has not proper contents.

How i can achieve this task with above requirements in parallel. I am using C#.net. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this code should work for you.

```
  var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\mydir");
  Parallel.ForEach(filePaths, ProcessFile);
```

Here is your processing logic

```
  private void ProcessFile(string filePath)
  {
      //do what you have to do here. Proper exception handling is needed in this method      
  }
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Will it work if there is any exception during the file processing and how i will handle the exception in parallel programming ?

Comment: There can be situations where you have exceptions while processing a file. (Ex: File is locked). So you need to handle them in `ProcessFile` method. Another possibility is that you have so many files in the directory and if you try to process all of them in multiple threads, you will have memory/processor usage issues. It makes sense to move file to another directory as soon as you start processing it. So another thread wont pick it up.

Comment: If you are expecting 1000s of files in this directory, it makes sense to partition your files collection in to 10 files each and process partition by partition. So you will have only 10 threads running at a time instead of 1000 threads.

Comment: Actually i have a windows service schedule for every 30 seconds and there is any file in the directory it will pick it to process. It could be 100 files or it could be 1 file but the requirement is to process the file without freezing the application. So should i go for Threads or TPL ?

Comment: I would use `Parallel`. As I said before if you are not sure about the file size and number of files, It is better to partition your files collection. But 100 small (~10mb) files should be fine.